# ffmpeg not working for AWS S3 signed urls

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert video format from `mp4` to `wav`. It works fine with public urls:

```
ffmpeg -i https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-fake-bucket/folder1/video.mp4 -vn -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 44100 -ac 2 video.wav
```

But when i use AWS's `signed-url` to convert it reports

```
[https @ 0x1bf6c40] HTTP error 400 Bad Request
```

Any idea what needs to be done for accessing signed urls using ffmpeg.?

Comment: You need to pass the AWS credentials in the request parameters

Comment: Can you show us your exact command line with a signed URL, minimally redacted (removing/altering only the signature and bucket name).

Answer (score 4):

Try putting the signed url under double quotes. That should do the trick. The special characters present in the signed url sometimes interfere with shell interpretation.